# Every extension of R that is a subfield of C is finite

Tags: galois-theory

Every extension of R that is a subfield of C is finite. This statement is false and I have a couple of counter examples, are they correct?

1. Consider the field extension $\mathbb{R}(x)$, the field of rational functions over $\mathbb{R}$. This field contains infinitely many transcendental elements, including the variable $x$, which is transcendental over $\mathbb{R}$. Since $\mathbb{R}(x)$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$, it serves as a counterexample to the claim that every extension of $\mathbb{R}$ that is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ is finite.
2. Consider the field of real algebraic numbers, denoted by $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. This field consists of all real numbers that are roots of non-zero polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$. The field $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ is infinite because there are infinitely many algebraic numbers over $\mathbb{Q}$. Additionally, since $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ (every algebraic number is also a complex number), it provides another counterexample to the claim that every extension of $\mathbb{R}$ that is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ is finite.

Comment: $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$ are the only subfields of $\mathbb C$ containing $\mathbb R$

Comment: $\Bbb R(x)$ is not a subfield of $\Bbb C$. The elements of $\Bbb C$ are complex numbers, not functions.

Comment: The real algebraic numbers are not an extension of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @jjagmath Technically with AC there are subfields of $\Bbb C$ that are isomorphic to $\Bbb R(x)$ (although they aren't extensions of the copy of $\Bbb R$ whose algebraic closure is the whole field).

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio I know, but being isomorphic doesn't mean that they are equal. As another easier example that doesn't require AC, $\Bbb Q(x)$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Q(\pi)$ but that doesn't make $\pi$ a rational function of degree $1$, $\pi$ is a real number.